# How to raycasting hidden object or not add to scene in Threejs

Tags: three.js

I created 1000 hidden objects with `BoxGeometry` geometry using THREE.JS. I set `object.visible = false` to hide each object, however this causes the raycasting/interaction to not work.

I expect that hiding the objects will give me a performance boost.

I can hide the box objects by setting `material.visible = false` on each object, however the performance of my app is still terrible.

How can I achieve the required raycasting interaction with hidden objects in the performance friendly way?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you require would be to not add your Box objects to your scene which would ensure that they are not rendered, and pass those directly to a [`THREE.Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster) to determine if intersection between any of those boxes has occurred.

You could for instance crate a `THREE.Raycaster` object from your `ray` primitive, and then pass an array of your Box objects to the `.intersectObjects()` method to determine ray intersection.

In code, that would look something like this:

```
// ray is your intersection primitive
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(ray.origin, ray.direction);

// boxObjects is an array of THREE.Object3D's representing your 1000 boxes
const intersectionResult = raycaster.intersectObjects(boxObjects)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. It working, but position of boxes not add to scene isn't updated. how can I update position of these boxes ?

Comment: You're welcome - does this work for you: `box.position.set( 4 , 5 , 6 ) // Set box position to [4,5,6]` ?

Comment: I set positon for each box, but it not working if not add to scene, It is alway at (0,0,0)